# Coin Change Dynamic Programming

Tags: recursion, dynamic-programming

QUESTION:
I'm having trouble finding the minimum amount of coins needed to reach a specific sum. I'm pretty sure this is done easiest recursively and using the dynamic programming methodology, I should basically get Math.min("takeACoin","leaveACoin");
Unfortunately, My code doesn't terminate though I do have if statements that terminate under the condition that the sum is met, the array of coins is depleted, or if the sum is over. Please look at my code below and let me know what I'm doing wrong and especially why my code continues executing until it receives a stackoverflow error though I have the appropriate terminating conditions.

CODE:

```
    private static final int S = 3;
public static int arr[] = {1,2};
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Interview i = new Interview();
    i.sumCoins(arr, 0);
}
public int sumCoins(int[] ar, int sum) {
    //if the sum is met, dont add any coins, just return 0
    if(sum == S){
        return 0;
    }
    //if the sum is greater, then return max value as it is impossible to get less sum
    if(sum > S){
        return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    }
    //if the array is out of coins return max value
    if(ar.length == 0){
        return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    }
    //if the sum is less than S and there is still more coins to use, keep checking
    //add the first coin
    int tmpSum = sum + ar[0];
    //delete the first coin from the list
    int[] tmp = Arrays.copyOfRange(ar, 1, ar.length);
    //add one coin to the solution
    int one = 1+sumCoins(tmp, tmpSum);
    //don't add one coin to the solution
    int two = sumCoins(ar,sum);

    //see which is more minimized
    return Math.min(one,two);
}
```

Requested Stack Trace:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError 
at java.lang.Math.min(Math.java:879)    
at java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Arrays.java:2623)   
at Interview.sumCoins(Interview.java:28)    
at Interview.sumCoins(Interview.java:32)    
at Interview.sumCoins(Interview.java:32)

Comment: could you post the stacktrace also?

Comment: I have not analyzed the code yet, but you can check this link http://www.frattv.com/merge-sort-java-implementation-error/

Comment: I did not find any applicability of the link to the problem I'm facing. I believe I'm still using my copy method correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question is in regards to how I was implementing my dynamic programming. I was using the original array in the case where you left the coin. this is incorrect. In more detail:
If you take the coin: get rid of the first (coin) index of the array, add the sum, add +1 for the number of coins. 
If you don't take the coin: get rid of the first (coin) index of the array since you're leaving that coin to not be considered.

In my solution, I received a stackoverflow because I was going through the "leaving the coin" scenario infinite times as the array never decreased and I wasn't actually "leaving the coin". 
Correct Code here:

```
private static final int S = 5;
public static int arr[] = {1,1,1,1,1};
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Interview i = new Interview();
    System.out.println(i.sumCoins(arr, 0));
}
public int sumCoins(int[] ar, int sum) {
    //if the sum is met, dont add any coins, just return 0
    if(sum == S){
        return 0;
    }
    //if the sum is greater, then return global array (not local)
    //length +1 as it's impossible to get more coins than indices
    if(sum > S){
        return arr.length+1;
    }
    //if the array is out of coins return max value
    if(ar.length == 0){
        return arr.length+1;
    }
    //if the sum is less than S and there is still more coins to use, keep checking
    //add the first coin
    int tmpSum = sum + ar[0];
    //delete the first coin from the list
    int[] tmp = Arrays.copyOfRange(ar, 1, ar.length);
    //add one coin to the solution
    int one = 1+sumCoins(tmp, tmpSum);
    //don't add one coin to the solution
    int two = sumCoins(tmp,sum);

    //see which is more minimized
    return Math.min(one,two);

}
```